# Applying the weights of a tf.keras.Model manually to input data

Tags: tensorflow, model

I know this may sound silly, but I'm just curious, what could be the reason behind it?

I manually performed calculations using the weights of the model and found slight discrepancies compared to the results obtained using the predict function.

Is it simply due to the excessive number of decimal places causing the inaccuracy, or are there other reasons?

The following is the  code I used for manual testing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import itertools
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import BinaryAccuracy #model evaluation
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping #regularization


all_numbers = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=8))
new_list = np.array(all_numbers)

#Casually copying some data
for i in range (10):
  new_list = np.append(new_list, new_list, axis=0)

# create model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(8,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')
])

# compile
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[BinaryAccuracy()])
early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='binary_accuracy', patience=15, restore_best_weights=True)
train_history=model.fit(new_list,new_list,epochs=20,callbacks=[early_stopper],verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)


#%% use predict function
test_data = np.array([[1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]])
#predict test_data
predictions = model.predict(test_data)

with np.printoptions(suppress=True):
    print(predictions)

#%% manual
def weight_cal(data,layer_num,node_index,input_size):
  sum=0
  bias=model.layers[layer_num].get_weights()[1][node_index]
  for i in range(0,input_size):
    sum+=data[i]*model.layers[layer_num].get_weights()[0][i][node_index]
  sum+=bias #bias
  return sum

test_data = [1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]
layer1_node=[]
layer2_node=[]


layer=0
for i in range(6):
  layer1_node+=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid([weight_cal(test_data,layer,i,8)]).numpy().tolist()

layer=1
for i in range(8):
  layer2_node+=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid([weight_cal(layer1_node,layer,i,6)]).numpy().tolist()


print(f"{layer2_node}")
```

Here are the results after a training session：

- predict　function:

  `[0.9793942, 0.9747051, 0.8871566, 0.01569304, 0.9999997, 0.0000001, 0.02251973, 0.09683841]`
- manual:

  `[0.97939413, 0.97470512, 0.88715659, 0.015693016, 0.99999968, 9.846270936008288e-08, 0.022519830, 0.096838386]`